# AG Grid Export Excel download failure and timer callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, export-to-excel, ag-grid-react

In AG-grid how do I know following when calling [exportDataAsExcel](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/excel-export-api/#reference-export-exportDataAsExcel):

1. Download has completed successfully
2. Download failed
3. Know that certain time has passed that user-initiated download, and it is still being processed if data being exported is large.

Is there any way or callback or lifecycle hook to do this. Please let me know the feasibility of it.

The end goal is to display proper message to user. I have toast already ready for it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Unfortunately, this solution only works for browser extensions and not for a SPA. The browser object is only available in web extenstions.

AG Grid itself does not have that functionality. What might help you is the downloads API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/onChanged

```
handleDownloadChanged = (e) => {
  // check export filename and status of download
  if (e.filename == "yourExportFilename.xlsx" && e.state.current === "complete") {
    console.log(`Download ${e.filename} has completed.`);
  }
}

browser.downloads.onChanged.addListener(this.handleDownloadChanged);
```

The state object contains three possible states:

> **in_progress** The browser is currently receiving download data from the
> server.
>
> **interrupted** An error broke the connection with the server.
>
> **complete** The download completed successfully.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/State

Comment: will this work in react with Chrome browser?

Comment: what import I need to do in my code for this?

Comment: You won't need any imports since this is backed into JavaScript itself. And yes, Chrome is supported. You can check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/DownloadItem#browser_compatibility

Comment: Small correction: the code above is written in TypeScript.

Comment: browser is not defined, I see this in browser console

Comment: how to have this in React?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, please see my edit in the answer.